# How to identify the web element for Selenium using the HTML code

Tags: selenium

How to identify the web element for login which is a dropdown with user name and password for Selenium using the HTML code:

HOME
                        SOLUTIONS

FEATURES

PRICING

```
                    <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll" onclick="setHash('team')">CLIENTS</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="http://blog.synctag.com" class="smoothScroll">BLOG</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll" onclick="setHash('contact')">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li id="resellerTab" style="display:none;"><a href="/Price" class="smoothScroll">AFFILIATE</a></li>
                    <li class="hidden-md visible-xs"><a href="/Account/Login" class="smoothScroll">LOGIN</a></li>
                    <li class="hidden-xs">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">LOGIN <i class="caret"></i></a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdownCustamaize">

                            <div class="form-box">
                                <div class="form-box-inner">
                                    <div class="row">
```

Email or username

```
    </div>
    <!--//form-group-->
    <div class="form-group password">
        <label class="sr-only" for="login-password">Password</label>
        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control login-password" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="login-password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        <p class="forgot-password">
            <a href="/Account/ForgotPassword" onclick="return SyncTagLoading();">Forgot Password?</a>
        </p>
        <div class="c-in" id="Guest" data-value="" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: You can check [Selenium documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) (Python) if you don't know how to locate element

Comment: Which `WebElement` are you trying to identify? How about your _code trials_?

Answer (score 0):

Here the XPath as

```
//div[@class='form-box-inner']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for login, the you can try this :

1. Link text : **LOGIN**
2. Partial link Text :   **LOGIN**
3. **XPATH** : `//a[contains(text(),'LOGIN') and @data-toggle='dropdown']`

you have not tagged any binding language, So it is hard to give you the optimize solution and code.